# Binding to <time>.datetime attribute in Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I'm tying to create a component which has a `<time/>` tag in it. And I'm trying to binding to its `datetime` attribute. Sample:

```
// component:

String isoFormat;

<!-- html template: -->

<time datetime="{{isoFormat}}">{{display}}</time>
```

But, I'm getting this compile-time error:

> ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Can't bind to 'datetime' since it isn't a known
>   native property or known directive. Please fix typo or add to
>   directives list.

Is there any fix for that? Or I should drop it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since datetime is a native HTML5 attribute, did you try prefixing it with `attr.`?

E.g.:

`<time [attr.datetime]="isoFormat">{{display}}</time>`

See here: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/template-syntax#other-bindings

Answer (score 0):

Either do what Crazywater suggested or use `dateTime` instead of `datetime`

```
<time dateTime="{{isoFormat}}">{{display}}</time>
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTimeElement

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qztcr9) (`in app/app.component.html`) it's TypeScript but it doesn't matter for this example.